# Can't use base_url() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to echo base_url() like so:

**editor_header.php**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

**The controller for editor_header.php looks like so:**

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {

        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
            $this->load->view('head&foot/editor_header', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

**I have enabled url_helper in autoload.php like so**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

But I still get the error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/editor/application/controllers/pages.php on line 5
```

pages.php is the controller above.

## My Question

Please could anyone advise why editor_header.php can't use base_url? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the entire error message?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: did you set the base_url in config.php file......

Comment: try instead of base_url use ROOT_FOLDER..........

Comment: what base url u yor define in confing file?

Comment: which one is line no 5?

Comment: Why do you think the issue is with your `base_url()` call? The error specifically was thrown in your pages.php controller file.

Comment: Can you post the entire controller code? The error is in your controller not on your view

Comment: If you remove the `echo base_url()` from the view, then you don't get the error message?

Comment: There is a syntax error and its because of this line if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')).i think there is no issue of base_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller code like this to see if it works

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        $path   =   APPPATH . 'views/pages' . $page . '.php';
        if ( ! file_exists($path))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
        $this->load->view('head&foot/editor_header', $data);
    }
}
```